# set timezone per request in spring

Tags: java, spring, date, datetime

I have data in DB in `UTC` timezone and some logic on client which is timezone-specific.

There was a decision to return data from server in user's timezone, so there is a flow:

1. client-side detects user's timezone via javascript
2. sends it in custom header (i.e. `"X-TIMEZONE"`)
3. server intercepts request (in `Filter`) and sets current timezone for it (per-request)
4. server handles conversions and returns data to users in his timezone

So the problem is set request-scoped timezone, is it even possible?

I found out that `Timezone.setDefault()` sets timezone for application in general.

Thanks.

Comment: Store the timezone in a request-scoped Spring bean and use it when necessary (when working with dates and times). It is not possible to set a request-scoped timezone in the JVM, because the JVM itself does not know anything about scopes.

Comment: In Java8 there is an class ZonedDateTime. You can pass zone to dao and create zoned date time in it.

Comment: Actually, `TimeZone.setDefault` affects all threads of *all apps* running in that JVM. Do so only as a last resort. Instead pass an object representing the desired time zone and use it in optional time zone arguments.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully I am understanding your question correctly. I ran into a similar issue a couple weeks ago and this was my solution. My code was being hosted where the time was UTC so if your code isn't hosted there you can do this `Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` to make it UTC. The variable timezone that I am passing in is just the target timezone that I wanted. This basically adds or subtracts the milliseconds to convert it the time according to the timezone you want. The calendar object of time should be the time you are looking for.

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTime(date);
TimeZone localTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone);
int offSet = localTimeZone.getOffset(date.getTime());
time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, time.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + offSet);
```

Within this link you can find a list of valid timezone options.http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: This is a poor approach. You should not be calculating an adjustment for offset yourself. Let the date-time classes do the actual calculations and adjustments. Aldo, you are using old troublesome classes that have been supplanted by java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect the client's time zone. But ultimately the only sure way to determine the user’s desired time zone is to ask her/him.

`TimeZone.setDefault` affects all code in all all threads of *all* apps running in that JVM. Do so only as a last resort. Instead pass an object representing the desired time zone and use it in optional time zone arguments.

The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have been supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of the functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in ThreeTen-Backport, and further adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP.

Get the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

To create a String that represents that value, call `toString` or use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow got many examples.